# get_post_terms not working as expected

Tags: terms, taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "Fruit" and under this I have a hierarchical taxonomy called, "Fruit Categories"

When I create a new post under Fruit, I am able to assign it to a "term" - like you would with a normal post category, but under the Fruit Categories taxonomy.

I've added three posts to Fruit, with each assigned to a single term respectively; "Apples", "Pears" and "Bananas".

All this works fine, but now I want to create an archive page that simply lists the terms in a UL, for that custom post type, like so;

mysite.com/fruit

- Apples
- Pears
- Bananas

This problem I am facing is that every query I have used only seems to return the first term, Apples.  The other two are not showing and I've tried many code snippets, all with the same avail.

Some things I've tried;

```
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'fruit_categories', array("fields" => "all"));  print_r($term_list);
```

And

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'fruit_categories');
$count = count($terms);

if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'fruit_categories').'">'. $term->name . "</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

I also tried the tips suggested here, however, this still results in the same issue with just the first term being listed.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502811/display-current-post-custom-taxonomy-in-wordpress

It's a fresh install with no plugins.

Do I need to add a foreach loop to pull in the additional terms?  Or is there something I am missing here?

I've also been looking at wp_get_object_terms but I don't really understand how to use it.

When I do a screen dump, I get the following on mysite/fruit

Apples

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 43 [name] => Apples[slug] => apples [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 43 [taxonomy] => fruit_categories [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 2 ) )

For what it's worth, here is my Custom Post Type and taxonomy registry code
http://pastebin.com/K8kwuzqt

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: For `count` you should reference `$terms->count` instead, as the return of the `wp_get_post_terms` contains more than a simple array. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: Thanks - I got this from the codex. Are you saying this $count = count($terms); should be $count = $terms->count; instead?

Comment: Actually I tried your main code block and it worked perfectly. So, you might be calling something else incorrectly. Perhaps it only *does* have the one term? Nevermind what I said about `count`

Comment: After you define `$terms`, try doing `var_dump($terms)` to see what it contains. This is a useful way to debug an object.

Comment: Hmmm well then there is something else amiss for me, as this definitely only pulls in the single term, even though each term is being used. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood what you were trying to do before. I thought you wanted to list the terms associated with one particular post - the one you are on. Whoops!

Try this instead:

```
    $terms = get_terms('fruit_category');
    if(!empty($terms)){ 
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'fruit_categories').'">'. $term->name . "</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
```

This will get you a list of all the links to the `term` pages, provided each term has at least one post in it.

#### Update:

To get taxonomy terms a bit more dynamically, can do this:

```
// taxonomy term archives
$post_type = get_post_type();
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
if(!empty($taxonomies)){
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        if(!empty($terms)){ 
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy).'">'. $term->name . "</a></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah - that's it ! Thank you GhostTrain - can't believe that is so simple and I missed it.  It is now correctly outputting the 3 fruit categories correctly.  Big ups to you!! :-)

Comment: Lol GhostTrain. No problem. Sorry I led you around the wrong way before.

Comment: haha sorry - I was so excited I can't read !  LOL

Comment: GhostToast - can you help a little more - I promise to get your name right this time (though my own folly did make me laugh)  How would I modify $terms = get_terms('fruit_category'); to check dynamically for the CPT (according to the current page) - i.e. without having to specify "fruit_category"  ?

Comment: Will add to answer as it won't look right here...

Comment: OK - part of the way there - the only issue with this is that it seems to return all of the post_tags too!

Comment: Sounds like it is time for you to ask a new question ;)

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for all you help Much appreciated :-)