# Strip post_tags from list of returned taxonomy terms

Tags: advanced-taxonomy-queries

Thanks to [GhostToast for helping me on my way with this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103379/get-post-terms-not-working-as-expected#103386).

Now I am successfully able to echo out all of the taxonomy associated terms dynamically.
However, this unfortunately also seems to spit out all the site's post_tags too.

So how can I use the following code, but not show the standard post_tags (I'd like to keep the post_tags available for use, just not show them as a result of this query)

```
// taxonomy term archives
$post_type = get_post_type();
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
if(!empty($taxonomies)){
foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    if(!empty($terms)){ 
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.     $term->name . "</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to determine if Taxonomy is hierarchical or not:

[Function Reference/is taxonomy hierarchical « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_taxonomy_hierarchical)

Example:

```
// taxonomy term archives
$post_type = get_post_type();
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
if(!empty($taxonomies)){
foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
    // only want hierarchical -- no tags please
    if(is_taxonomy_hierarchical($taxonomy)){
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
        if(!empty($terms)){ 
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.     $term->name . "</a></li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
    }
}

} // this was missing
```

Comment: Thank you GT! Unfortunately that results in Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_taxonomy_hierarchial().  Googling it appears to show many sites with the same issue, but no actual answers.  Presumably I need to add something to functions file?

Comment: Oops. Was typo. hierarchical == tough word.

Comment: lol - I missed that too!  Sending you a big high five along with a crate of your favourite wishes for the day (and a spell chekrr).  Thanks HEAPS GhostToast!! :-) Would be happy to connect with you socially if you're on G+ or Twits?

Comment: I hang out in WPSE chat if you wanna shoot the breeze sometime http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop. Please mark answer as accepted if this answer works for you, thanks.

Comment: Done. All good - cheers

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "I'd like to keep the post_tags available for use" but I see two options here:

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
$taxonomies = array_diff($taxonomies,array('post_tag'));
// and then your Loop
```

Or ...

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies($post_type);
if(!empty($taxonomies)){
  foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
    if ('post_tag' === $taxonomy) continue;
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
    if(!empty($terms)){ 
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy).'">'.     $term->name . "</a></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. GhostToast's answer worked perfectly for me.

Comment: No need to post "thank you" comments. That is what voting is for :)